# Filtering on datagrid with WPF MVVM, it works but I don't know why

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So the thing is, yesterday I wanted to make a searchbar for filtering a datagrid. I succeded in doing this but when I was looking it over today i realized I have no idea why it's working. Here's what's confusing me:

Basically I have a datagrid with its ItemsSource set to an ObservableCollection called Equipments. In order to filter on Equipments I have also created an ICollectionView called EquipmentView, which is just a mirror of Equipments that I can do filtering on.

Equipments is populated in the viewmodel from a table in my database like this:

```
 public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var lookup = await _equipmentLookupDataService.GetEquipmentLookupAsync();
            Equipments.Clear();
            foreach (var item in lookup)
            {
                Equipments.Add(item);
            }
            EquipmentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Equipments);
            EquipmentView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "An error occurred", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            //create new error object from the exception and add to DB
            Error error = new Error
            {
                ErrorMessage = e.Message,
                ErrorTimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                ErrorStackTrace = e.StackTrace,
                LoginId = CurrentUser.LoginId
            };
            await _errorDataService.AddError(error);
        }
    }
```

EquipmentView.Filter calls the Filter method:

```
 public bool Filter(object obj)
    {
        var data = obj as EquipmentLookup;

        if (EquipmentView != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString))
            {
                string allcaps = _filterString.ToUpper();
                return data.TypeName.StartsWith(_filterString) || data.TypeName.StartsWith(allcaps);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It returns true only when the TypeName property starts with the filterstring, which is the string that's bound to my searchbar.

Now I THOUGHT I just had to set the datagrid ItemsSource to EquipmentView. If I do that everything works fine and the datagrid only shows whatever matches with the searchbar.

Apparently though, if I set the itemsSource on the datagrid back to Equipments it still works, searchbar included. Why is this? As far as I understand me filtering on EquipmentView shouldn't change anything about Equipments, but it seems to do so anyway.

Everything works fine really, I just wish I knew why.

Also XAML-code for searchbar:

```
<TextBox Name="SearchBar" Margin="10 10 10 10" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid MaxHeight="800"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Equipments}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEquipment, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                     Handler="Row_DoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: When you bind to a collection, WPF is actually binding to the default view of that collection. The view is just a wrapper that enables you to filter, sort, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the WPF documentation:

> All collections have a default CollectionView. WPF always binds to a
>   view rather than a collection. If you bind directly to a collection,
>   WPF actually binds to the default view for that collection. This
>   default view is shared by all bindings to the collection, which causes
>   all direct bindings to the collection to share the sort, filter,
>   group, and current item characteristics of the one default view.

Now in your code, you're doing this:

```
EquipmentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Equipments);
EquipmentView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
```